# how to use multiple selector or nested selector in scss mixin

Tags: css, sass

I want to get css code like this

```
.img-wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper image {
    width: 100px;
}
```

I want to use mixin in scss like this

```
@mixin fixed-img($width, $height) {
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
    overflow: hidden;

    ...
}

.img-wrapper {
    @include fixed-img(100px , 100px);
}
```

Can I get the the above css output by using only one mixin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the parent selector `&` inside the mixin and define the rule for the nested `img` element

```
@mixin fixed-img($width, $height) {
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
    overflow: hidden;

    & img {
       width: $width;
    }
}

.img-wrapper {
    @include fixed-img(100px , 100px);
}
```

Note that instead of

```
& img {
    width: $width;
}
```

You may avoid to use the SASS variable and use `inherit` keyword (or also `100%`)

```
 & img {
    width: inherit;
 }
```